# How can a single skill be linked for multiple objects created in AWS IoT independently?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot, alexa-slot

I'm developing a hardware that obeys voice commands from an Alexa skill.

The skill is associated with a lambda function that has the name of the AWS iot object and the endpoint of the skill.

Everything works very well.

But when I want to distribute my skill, it will obviously only work for my hardware.

I want to build multiple devices, that means creating multiple objects in AWS iot.

My question when the user downloads the Skill, how can it be configured so that he can enter the name of the object, of the hardware that the user has purchased.

So far the most absurd and crappy solution I can think of is to create a skill for each of the devices.

Any suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is through the smart home skill API. The pattern it defines decouples the skill logic with the logic to control individual devices. This makes your system more complicated, but as you've pointed out any solution using a single skill lambda is going to be pretty "crappy."

This documentation article explains how to use the smart home skill API better than I could.
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/understand-the-smart-home-skill-api.html

Comment: Possibly the solution is here, but it is not clear to me yet:

https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/questions/242312/how-can-a-single-skill-be-linked-for-multiple-obje.html

Comment: Not possibly but definitely. This forum post suggests using smart home skills, the same exact thing I'm suggesting in this answer. The smart home skill system is designed precisely to solve the problem you are encountering.

Comment: But the microcontroller manufacturers that use the Shadows example, start from a custom skill, never mention or use the smart home skills.

A few hours ago MCHP answered and says that they use AWS Cognito and AWS DynamicDB, nothing related to gadget registration. In the link above, in the last answer I put everything they commented.